# Tools to Synchronise db schema across multiple database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there any tools that will synchronize db schema between multiple database?

I have taken separate db per tenant approach, means I will have separate db per tenant/customer for recording their application data.

Now while I am upgrading my application, I need to update schema across 100s of db in order to deploy updates.

So is there any tools/scripts which will roll db schema change across all other dbs in case of update/db changes

Edit:

Here Synchronize means, I want to have same schema over all dbs as they will be accessed by same code base for transaction of different tenants/customers.

Comment: You could wrap a PS script around a tool like [`dbup`](https://dbup.github.io/), or any other tool that allows scripting.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by *synchronize*?